# How get row from sales_order_item table by item_id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, order-items

How get specific row from  `sales_order_item` by giving `item_id`?
Which collection use to filter row?
Can anyone guide me ? has any direct or indirect way to fetch `sales_order_item` record from `item_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the repository.

> use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface;

```
/**
 * @var OrderItemRepositoryInterface
 */
private $orderItemRepository;


public function __construct(
    OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderItemRepository
) {
    $this->orderItemRepository = $orderItemRepository;
}
```

Now:

```
$orderItem = $this->orderItemRepository->get(4);
error_log($orderItem->getName());
```